# MongoDB .NET Find().ToList() operation slow for large result

Tags: c, .net, mongodb

I have a collection that is about 5 GB, consisting of roughly 26000 entries. These entries have a field "System", and for this test, all entries have the same value for this.

If I run the following code:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("System",sys);
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

The code runs seemingly forever, and consumes ridiculous amounts of memory, up towards 20 gigs when I've let it run for a while before aborting.

Is there a more efficient way of collecting these documents, or do I need to solve this some other way?

Comment: Paging? Get only a portion at a time. With 5GB of data you would expect it to be little slow.

Comment: Slow, sure, but the operation doesn't seem to finish at all. The same query in the mongo shell takes a few seconds.

Comment: Query in the shell only returns fixed number of results. It is actually paging. Also note that `ToList()` call actually tries to get `all` data ... the entire filter result.

Comment: What is the count of the filter? How many records?

Comment: The count is 26 397. I need to get all of the data, because I need to extract a list of objects from each entry for a subsequent operation.

Comment: Why can't you page through the data until you get it all and then do the next operation? Get 1K at a time ... 27 pages and you are golden.

Comment: It does look promising, though I'm not entirely sure how to implement it. I'll give it a go.